# How do you turn off colored text in testthat?

Tags: r, devtools, testthat

I use the package [colorout](http://www.lepem.ufc.br/jaa/colorout.html) to color my output in R (I don't use RStudio). When running tests in `testthat` it also prints out in color interfering with the colorout package printing a lot of color codes.

Here is an example of the output:

```
R> library(colorout)
R> devtools::test()
Loading mypackage
Testing mypackage
1;32m.0m1;32m.0m1;32m.0m
```

How can I turn off coloring in `testthat`?

Comment: There's already [an issue](https://github.com/hadley/testthat/issues/153) addressing this.

Comment: Yes, seems to be implemented already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found that there is an option for this:

```
options(testthat.use_colours = FALSE)
```